# Windows 2016 server essentials in qemu kvm on gentoo linux will not boot

Tags: windows, kvm-virtualization

I can finish the initial installation of Windows 2016 server essentials with Qemu and libvirt on gentoo linux. But on first launch the VM will get a BSOD on first boot after installation.

Subsequent restarts display a popup window that says

> "The computer restarted unexpectedly or encountered an unexpected
>   error. Windows installation cannot proceed. To install Windows, click
>   "OK" to restart the computer, and then restart the installation."

This article has the exact behavior I am experiencing except I do not get the log messages. https://gist.github.com/jorritfolmer/d01194a00f440ad257bd56d51baddc2d

I created `/etc/modprobe.d/kvm.conf` file and added the line:

```
options kvm ignore_msrs=1
```

but still does not work. Tried renaming to qemu.conf.
Also tried adding `kvm.conf` to `/etc/libvirt/` and `/etc/qemu/` (just a wag)

Tested with both:

- linux 4.10.13-aufs, qemu 2.9.0-r2, libvirt 3.3.0
- linux 4.15.14-aufs, qemu-2.11.1-r2, libvirt 4.1.0

Here is the xml

```
<domain type='kvm' id='1'>
  <name>WinEss</name>
  <uuid>3815d313-1a83-4f2c-9348-d5f8726ed05d</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>8388608</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>8388608</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-2.4'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <vmport state='off'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='full'>
    <model fallback='forbid'>Westmere</model>
    <feature policy='require' name='vme'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='pclmuldq'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='x2apic'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='hypervisor'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='arat'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/antlets/WinEss/Blank.qcow2'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <alias name='ide0-0-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/antlets/WinEss/antsle:volumes/WinEss.iso'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='hdb' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <alias name='ide0-0-1'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'>
      <alias name='pci.0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='b2:61:6e:73:6c:0f'/>
      <source network='bblv' bridge='virbr1'/>
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <model type='e1000'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/1'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
    </input>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input2'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5900' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <alias name='sound0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' vgamem='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='none' model='none'/>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='dac' relabel='yes'>
    <label>+77:+77</label>
    <imagelabel>+77:+77</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
</domain>
```

---

Update 8/10/18
I have tried changing the cpu type to core2duo and host-passthrough and all the cpu types in the cpu_map.xml
I have tried several variations with some examples from the libvirt.org documentation

```
<cpu match='exact'>
  <model fallback='allow'>core2duo</model>
  <vendor>Intel</vendor>
  <topology sockets='1' cores='2' threads='2'/>
  <cache level='3' mode='emulate'/>
  <feature policy='disable' name='lahf_lm'/>
</cpu>
```

I did find another article recommending host-passthrough but I am not sure if I am configuring it properly in the xml.
again with several variations with and without 'feature', 'cache', 'check'... with info from libvirt.org

```
<cpu mode='host-passthrough' check='none'>
  <cache mode='passthrough'/>
</cpu>

<cpu mode='host-passthrough' check='none'>
  <topology sockets='1' cores='1' threads='4'/>
  <cache mode='passthrough'/>
  <feature policy='disable' name='lahf_lm'/>
</cpu>
```

and just

```
<cpu>
  <topology sockets='1' cores='1' threads='4'/>
</cpu>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to reboot after creating the file with the KVM module options.

```
options kvm ignore_msrs=1
```

Its name does not matter, as long as it is in the `/etc/modprobe.d` directory and ends with `.conf`.

---

You also should create your machines with Q35 machine type (never I440FX even though it's the default). I440fx is an ancient 1996-era motherboard and modern Windows doesn't really care for it.

Also you should set CPU to either core2duo or host-passthrough. Windows 10 upgrades very often fail when using any other CPU type. Use host-passthrough if you intend to run Hyper-V in the VM or you desperately need every last bit of performance; core2duo otherwise.

Comment: Michael, Thanks for responding... I did reboot and the file is in the correct directory with a .conf extension.

Comment: @mak64 What is your processor, then?

Comment: The cpu is an Avoton C2550 on which I can run Windows server 2016, 2012R2 and Win 10 with no problem.  I am going to test on a different machine with a xeon processor and a similar build.

Comment: same results with the xeon processor.

Comment: Post the libvirt XML for this guest.

Comment: Ok, posted the xml above

Comment: @mak64 Hm. Windows 10/2016 in KVM is very sensitive to CPU type, either set it to core2duo or host-passthrough. Also enable HPET or you'll get poor performance.

Comment: I tried core2duo and host-passthrough with several variations.  I think the host-passthrough may be the direction but not sure if I am configuring it correctly... updated the post above

Comment: @mak64 Oh, you are using the ancient i440fx machine type. This emulates a 1996-era motherboard and modern Windows really doesn't like it. I only use q35 machine type for all VMs. You can't just change it though. You'll have to create a new VM in virt-manager.